# convert from decimal latitude/longitude to 24 bit or 3 byte

Tags: 24-bit

I need to convert the decimal latitude/longitude value to signed 24bit valuse . 
 For latitude example 37.256526 value converted to signed 24 bit.
 The specification is blow.

```
The latitude is coded with 24 bits: 1 bit of sign and a number between 0 and 2^23-1 coded in binary on 23 bits. The relation between the coded number N and the range of (absolute) latitudes X it encodes is the following (X in degrees):
```

Comment: Even after correction of spelling and mark-up errors, this post remained unintelligible.